# sbt-assembly won't include oracle ojdbc6.jar?

Tags: sbt-assembly

sbt version 0.13.13

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.4")
```

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "oracle" % "oracle-jdbc" % "11.2.0.4.0"
)
```

When I run `sbt assembly` it includes all the other dependencies in the fat jar *except* oracle!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very obscure but I'll tell the story anyway.

Turns out the oracle jar was corrupted in our nexus (looks like it had http headers at the beginning of it, as if someone had used `curl -v` and piped the output to a file as a way of downloading the jar...)

Some tools are more forgiving of this fact than others, which was masking the problem.  Intellij is fine with it.  The JVM is fine with it.  But `sbt-assembly` silently ignores the problem and just doesn't include the class files.   Only `sbt-native-packager` gives you a handy warning that gives a clue as to the problem:

`warning [/tmp/app/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/oracle.oracle-jdbc-11.2.0.4.0.jar]:  170 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)`

I could blame a teammate for uploading a corrupted jar and no checksum files to our nexus, but ultimately I blame Oracle for their licensing policy that forces you to host their jars yourself, and secondly I blame Sonatype for releasing a crippled Nexus V3 that does not have a UI for uploading artifacts, which tempts people to script things, and make mistakes like using `curl -v`.  Rant over.